# Any solution for reducing browser compatibility problem while writing css style as a web designer/web developer

Tags: asp.net, html, css

Any solution for reducing browser compatibility problem while writing css style.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These three are the main points you need to do yourself:

- Write correct markup - make sure it validates
- Make sure your markup is in standards mode
- Write correct CSS - make sure it validates

In addition, you can do some of the following to reduce the amount of headache:

- You can use a CSS framework, like Blueprint, 960.gs, YUI CSS library, etc.
- For Internet Explorer -related issues, there is ie7.js and ie8.js

Comment: I'd argue about the CSS validation... Triggering hasLayout under IE with zoom is a life-saver!

Comment: True, but you should always start with valid CSS. After it works in FF, Opera, Safari, you can then concentrate on creating styles that make it work in IE.

Comment: You're right, though it's harder to isolate problems when you have more markup :) Anyway, +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

- Know how HTML and CSS work
- Test in all browsers you target

You may also want to use a [CSS reset](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/) file to start on the common ground.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as of now there is nothing like fixall() which will make all browsers compatible...however, you can reduce compatibility problems by using the correct doctype.
[Read this](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/doctype/)article on using doctypes. Also, validate your markup.

Edit: You can go to [Browser shots](http://browsershots.org/) to see screenshots of your web design in different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Discipline!

- [Validate your HTML](http://validator.w3.org/). Use a correct [DOCTYPE](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_DOCTYPE.asp).
- Use standards, [hack the bugs](http://www.quirksmode.org/).
- Be descriptive, or use a [reset stylesheet](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/).

Comment: I'd argue that `css` and `html` hacks shouldn't be used. In any case, use conditional comments. Also, I don't really see the need of a reset stylesheet. I always override the styling of the `html` elements that I use. And leave the rest alone. Less bytes through the wire ;)

Comment: I myself don't use a reset stylesheet, though it's an option - that's what I meant about being descriptive. They mess up any content that you didn't have on the page while developing :P And conditional comments, while unobtrusive, are still a hack ;)

Comment: @Alexander Conditional comments are a **supported** hack - they work as the makers of IE intended. True CSS hacks rely on bugs in a brwoser's CSS parser, and are thus potentially breakable when they fix said bugs.

Answer (score -1):

Simple -- test, test, test.
First thing, you should have at least these browsers on your computer: FireFox3.5B , InternetExplorer7 (+ optional Safari 3, Google Chrome 2 Beta and Opera).
Now for a more definite answer:

- avoid css3 styling like "opacity" et cetera as CSS3 is not a standard yet. Instead use Javascript libraries like jQuery to apply those effects selectively
- avoid png transparency like the plague... instead use dithered gif transparency (this is now somewhat old, as it now works on IE7+)
- Test and test and test

Comment: Wouldn't consider Opera optional. Opacity works just fine as long as you remember to add IE-specific properties for it, as does PNG transparency

Comment: Not in that context, but FireFox and IE consist of the largest userbase. Also if it works in Firefox and IE , it should work in those...

Comment: Adding IE specific properties to the CSS invalidates it and makes it harder to work with styles when using javascript.